# Filter on `list(Int64)` dtype in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Say I have

```py
In [20]: df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [[1,2,3], [1,4,2], [1,3,3]], 'b': [4,2,1]})

In [21]: df
Out[21]:
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────────┬─────┐
│ a         ┆ b   │
│ ---       ┆ --- │
│ list[i64] ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪═════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 4   │
│ [1, 4, 2] ┆ 2   │
│ [1, 3, 3] ┆ 1   │
└───────────┴─────┘
```

I'd like to keep rows where `'a'` equals `[1,2,3]`

I've tried

```py
In [23]: df.filter(pl.col('a')==[1,2,3])

ArrowErrorException: NotYetImplemented("Casting from Int64 to LargeList(Field { name: \"item\", data_type: Int64, is_nullable: true, metadata: {} }) not supported")
```

but it raises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hash the list first and hash a literal and then compare the two:

```
df.filter(pl.col('a').hash() == pl.lit([[1,2,3]]).hash())
```

Answer (score 2):

By the error this function doesn't seem to be implemented yet

However you could add your own filter function - like this (accumulating your own column as a filter):

```py
from functools import reduce
def filterList(c: pl.col, l: list) -> pl.col:
    return reduce(lambda a,b: a & b, [c.list.get(idx) == item for idx, item in enumerate(l)])
```

or if you prefer the usual for loop-style:

```py
def filterList(c: pl.col, l: list) -> pl.col:
    res = pl.lit(True)
    for idx, item in enumerate(l):
        res = res & (c.list.get(idx) == item)
    return res
```

and then simply call

```
df.filter(filterList(pl.col('a'), [1,2,3]))
```

which should give you the right result even if the list entries in the original dataframe are shorter (because `.get(idx)`would simply return `null`)